# How can I assign a class method to a value within a HashMap?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I'm creating a text-based "Game of Real Life" program. I am struggling with finding an efficient way to allocate methods that will carry out the directions given by each tile of the game board (linear game board with definite start/finish points). Each player in the game is represented by an object of class "Player" containing variables for different game statistics (including a placeholder value for their position on the board), and every player object is contained within a hash map. I would like to create a loop that would cycle through each player object and, based on the respective placeholder value, reference a specific method for that tile of the board.

My Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coin coin = new Coin();
    Die die = new Die();
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Choose player amount:");
    int n = choice.nextInt();

    /*This map contains master list of all players and player values*/
    HashMap<Integer, Player> playerList = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();

    /*This map contains just the true_false value of life for each player*/
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> lifeCheck = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    /*This section defines number/sex/name of each player*/
    for (int y = 1; y <= n; y++) {
        System.out.println("New player now flips a coin.");
        coin.flip();
        if (coin.get() == true) {
            System.out.println("You flipped heads! You are a man.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You flipped tails! You are a woman.");
        }

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String user = choice.next();
        playerList.put(y, new Player(user));

        /*This adds a check functionality to ensure live players still exist*/
        lifeCheck.put(y, playerList.get(y).pulse());
    }

    /*This invokes a new instance of our game board*/
    GameSpace gameBoard = new GameSpace();/*Not yet defined*/

    /*This do_while loop checks that a live player exists after each turn*/
    do {
        /*This is where I think I would be putting the majority of
                   the game code*/  

    } while (lifeCheck.containsValue(true));

    /*This tests to see if my player naming loop works properly*/
    /*
    int x = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Player number " + x + " is named " + playerList.get(i).name);
        x++;
    }
    */





    choice.close();
}
}
```

My Player class:

```
public class Player {
public boolean gender;
public String name;
public int wealthClass;
public double income;
public double wealth;
public double health;
public boolean parent = false;
public boolean disabled = false;
public boolean alive = true;
public double placeHold = 1;

public Player(String playerName) {
    name = playerName;
}

public boolean getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public int getCaste() {
    return wealthClass;
}
public double getIncome() {
    return income;
}
public double getWealth() {
    return wealth;
}
public double getHealth() {
    return health;
}
public boolean getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public boolean getDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}
public boolean pulse() {
    return alive;
}
public double getPosition() {
    return placeHold;
}

public void move() {
    Die die1 = new Die();
    die1.roll();
    placeHold += die1.get();
    System.out.println("You moved forward " + die1.get() + " spaces.");
}

public void main(String[] args) {
    if (health <= 0) {
        alive = false;
    }
}
}
```

My Coin class:

```
public class Coin {
private boolean face;

public Coin() {
    flip();
}
public void flip() {
    double x = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
    if (x == 0) {
        face = true;
    } else {
        face = false;
    }
}
public boolean get() {
    return face;
}
}
```

Where would be the most logical place to go from here?

Comment: Please try to provide a complete, *minimal* example. Most of the code seems unrelated to your problem, and the only thing we have to work with is your title and last sentence. It's unclear what exactly your problem is, and why you want to do something with hashmaps and "placeholder values".

Comment: I want to use the Player class' placeHold integer value to directly reference a HashMap key that activates a method for the respective game tile. That is the best way of achieving my goal that I can see, but I have not been able to implement it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If the HashMap's value is the name of the method you want to call, you should be able to use reflection:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "methodName1");
map.put(1, "methodName2");    

String methodName = map.get(player.getPosition());
Method method = Player.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
method.invoke();
```

Comment: What if the methods are all in different classes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are asking how to store a method associated with each position on the board the specifies what to do at that position. If so, I would suggest you encapsulate it in the position. That would be best defined as an interface:

```
interface Position {
    void operateOnPlayer(Player player);
}
```

Then your board becomes a map from the distance from the start to a Position implementation:

```
Map<Integer,Position> board;
```

If you are using Java 8 then you can even use lambdas to define the positions:

```
board.put(17, player -> player.moveBack(4));
board.put(16, player -> player.skipATurn());
```

It will work just as well in previous versions of Java you'll just need to create (potentially anonymous) implementations of `Position`.

Calling these is then pretty trivial:

```
for (Player player: players)
    board.get(player.getPosition()).operateOnPlayer(player);
```

Or, even better, add that to the `Player` class so you don't need to expose the position field:

```
class Player {
    public takeTurn() {
        board.get(position).operateOnPlayer(this);
    }
}
```

There are other mechanisms, such as mapping to a `Consumer<Player>`, but I really don't think they are as good design as defining an explicit interface;